# When I'm opening gradle project in intellij, I don't get the option of creating package

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, plugins

Also, it doesn't creating me .gradle, gradle and build folders automatically after creating the folder.

[The picture of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMcVU.png)
[Picture of the wanted project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N2I8.png)

Comment: Do you open build.gradle file? Does the import complete without errors? Are there any exceptions in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?

Comment: I added two pictures, one for my project and one for the wanted project and files. It opened me build.gradle automatically. I don't see any exceptions at the when the project fails.

Comment: Option to create packages is available only for the source roots (marked in BLUE in the project view). Can you create packages inside `src/main/java` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You want creates Gradle or Maven Project you may this link will helpful for you https://start.spring.io/.

You can create project from browser and then can download.
For download click the Generate button or Ctrl+Enter.

If You are generate gradle project from browser it will suggest basic dependencies.